# Scrolling is not working when the container is not visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two tabs, first tab is a tab that shows video info, second tab has the comments on that video.
The comments sections has max-width and is scrollable.

I use a scroll function that scrolls to the bottom of the comments every time the component is rendered.

The problem is when I am on the video info tab and switch to the comments tab, the scrolling does not happen, it only happen when I add a new comment.

Why it does not scroll even when I am in the video tab so that when I open the comments tab I found it at the bottom ?

```
const scrollToBottom = () => {
    animateScroll.scrollToBottom({
        containerId: "blueprint-comments"
    });

}

useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
});
```

Comment: what is the implementation of those tabs? are you using some ui lib or react-router?

Comment: I am using antd (ANT design)  tabs

Comment: (∩⌣̀_⌣́) try using `useLayoutEffect`